# SQL Server 2014 installation

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation, sql-server-2014

I am going to develop web applications using asp.net for this I am first installing SQL server  during SQL install I stuck in selection of features

Can any one tell me which features of SQL server should I select to install as web developer.

Comment: Which edition are you installing? Express?

Comment: Just installing the DB engine along with client connectivity SDK would be enough.

Comment: SQL server Enterprise 2014

Comment: also need to use management studio in future.

Comment: That's why you need `client connectivity SDK`

Comment: Do you mean install a local instance on your PC for development, and target Enterprise Edition for deployment?  In that case, I suggest you install Developer Edition, which has all the features of EE but is licensed only for development (saving thousands USD in licensing costs).  You need only install the database engine, although installing complete client tools may come in handy.

Comment: @Rahul I just installed database engine with sql client connectivity SDK but it doesnt install any management studio with it .

Comment: To install SSMS you need to select Management tools in Feature selection

Comment: My bad ... you need to install `Mgmt tools` for SSMS from feature list as @MilicaMedic already pointed out. You can add a new feature at any time from the installation MSI.